# Dataplex zone dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-dataplex

I am learning about Dataplex. When I created a zone in Dataplex, it automatically created a dataset with the zone name in BigQuery (zone_a).

I registered one of my datasets as an asset of the zone and gave another user Dataplex.dataOwner permission on that zone.

The other user can freely access and modify the "dataset" dataset (registered zone asset) but cannot edit the "zone_a" dataset.

What is this "zone_a" dataset used for?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip6Yj.png

I tried to delete the zone_a dataset using the owner account, and it seems fine.